# Keycloak - Missing data in the userinfo response

Tags: openid, keycloak

When I hit `/auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo` I get very little details about the user.

```
{
    "sub": "ed291f7a-a799-4d8b-a776-e634d727668c",
    "email_verified": true,
    "preferred_username": "admin"
}
```

More info (such as role lists) is inside the access token that I'm actually sending to this endpoint. I could just decode the access token instead of hitting this endpoint, is this expected/normal behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: please, share the request you send to `userinfo` endpoint

Answer (score 6):

I managed to add 'Client roles' and 'Realm roles' to the Userinfo payload by doing the following:

1. go to Client Scopes > roles Mappers > realm roles
2. toggle on the 'Add to userinfo', and off the 'Add to token' ones
3. change the 'Token Claim Name' to whatever you want, anything would work

same applies for client roles, 1. becomes Client Scopes > roles Mappers > client roles 
**NB**: Roles have to be but in the 'Assigned' column in 'Scope' tab

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to make a custom mapper with a custom `Token Claim Name`. `realm_access.roles` from the predefined mappers didn't work fsr

Answer (score 1):

The fields present in the response are scoped by the claims present in the access token.

Keycloak is OpenID compliant.

OpenID spec [defines](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo):

> The UserInfo Endpoint is an OAuth 2.0 Protected Resource that returns
>   Claims about the authenticated End-User. To obtain the requested
>   Claims about the End-User, the Client makes a request to the UserInfo
>   Endpoint using an Access Token obtained through OpenID Connect
>   Authentication. These Claims are normally represented by a JSON object
>   that contains a collection of name and value pairs for the Claims.
>
> The Claims defined in [Section 5.1](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims) can be returned, as can
>   additional Claims not specified there.